# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I am doing a leaflet plugin and i have a problem with the calendar.

```
    var calen = L.DomUtil.create('div', className, container);
    calen.href = '#';
    L.DomEvent
        .addListener(calen, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation)
        .addListener(calen, 'click', L.DomEvent.preventDefault)
        .addListener(calen, 'click', this._buttonExtendCalendaClicked, this);

    calen.datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        altField: '#date-input',
        altFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        defaultDate: new Date().getTime()
    });
```

the error is: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I don't know how can I do it

Comment: Which line does the debugger tell you the problem is occurring on?

Answer (score 0):

`calen` is initialised by leaflet's `DomUtil.create()` which returns an `HTMLElement`

jqueryui defines its widgets as jquery plugins, so you need to wrap the HTMLElement in a jquery collection:

```
$(calen).datepicker({ /* ... options ... */ });
```

Comment: It's a common error, especially if you're not very familiar with the libraries. If the answer helped you consider [ticking it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)